# Footer height according to url?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, polymer

I have a page in which there are two different routers (url). I want to change the height according to url? Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

For exaple if I am on Root router I want to have the height of the footer 100 px and if I am on the other url I want the height to be 64px?

My code looks something like this

```
<view-router update-document-title testing>
        <ehr-welcome-page-view pattern="/"></ehr-welcome-page-view>
        <ehr-router-otherpattern="/other/*"></ehr-router-emis>
</view-router> 

<footer>
   <div class="footer-content-wrapper center-content border-right">
          <a href="http://www.mypage.co.uk/" target="_blank">
            <img src="./images/my-logotype.png" alt="MyLogotype">
          </a>
        </div>
        <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to return a class based on route params such as url.

```
<app-route    route="{{route}}" />
<div class$="footer-content-wrapper [[_getFooterHeightClass(route.path)]]">

_getFooterHeightClass(path) {
  switch(path) {
    case '/path/a': 
      return 'height-a';
    case '/path/b': 
      return 'height-b';
  }
}
```